# div going out of parents div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a question about a div being longer then it's parent div.

My page is looking as followed:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="top">
    </div><!--/top-->
    <div id="middle">
        <div id="keep_up">
            <div id="thread_menu">
                  <div id="new_thread">
                      New threads in here
                  </div>
                  <div id="active_thread">
                      Active threads in here
                  </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--/keep_up-->
    </div><!--/middle-->
    <div id="bottom">
    </div><!--/bottom-->
</div>
```

And the css (Will skip the top div since that is working fine).

```
html,body {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
    min-height:110%;/*Did this, so the page will be a little longer already*/
    position:relative; 
}

    #middle{
        width: 80%;
        margin-left: 10%;   
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }

    #bottom {
        color: white;
        background:#000;
        width:100%; 
        height:20px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom:0;
        left:0;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

#thread_menu{
    float: left;
    width: 17%;
}

#new_thread{
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    border-left: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    border-right: 2px solid black;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}

#active_thread{
    height: 80%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 5%;
    border-left: 2px #000 solid;
    border-bottom: 2px #000 solid;
    border-right: 2px #000 solid;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
```

Now, i fill the active and **new_thread** div with 15 items that i retrieve from my database. Same with **Active_thread** div. However, on a big screen the results will show fine (As it should). But on a small screen (laptop) it shows it like this:

[image: How the website looks on a small screen]

(The browser is not that big, you always need to scroll a little bit down in order to see the footer (See height: 110% in wrapper))

Question: how do i make my thread_menu push the footer down and keep it inside my wrapper or at least middle div?

(Used the tags Jquery and Javascript because i'm not sure how to solve this problem, and it might needs one of those).

Image EDIT:

[image: What it looks like when i do that]

Comment: Can you provide `fiddle` for that?

Comment: Il try, give me a moment

Comment: `#thread_menu` is floated. This means it's being taken out of the normal flow. It's possible the parent is collapsing. Try adding `overflow: auto` to `#keep_up`, or researching other [***clearfix methods***](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clearfix).

Comment: Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/oapdvcv0/ However in the fiddle it is working :/  @Michael_B It is then taking up the middle div (Like it should) But the content that is to the right of the thread menu is getting pushed down

Comment: Seems like you put `CSS` in `JS` section in `fiddle.`

Comment: Ooopssss :O https://jsfiddle.net/oapdvcv0/2/

Comment: @Mitch is [__This__](https://jsfiddle.net/mdehghani/oapdvcv0/3/) what you expect?

Comment: Yes @MehdiDehghani I made a edit to my post showing you what happends when i do that (Add overflow). It pushes my other content (That is to the right) down.

Comment: You didn't provide complete example, but I guess that problem is for `width`, can you try to change the `width` of  one of columns in `browser console` and tell if the issue solved?

Comment: @MehdiDehghani Did not want to include it all because it would be alot. In the new fiddle i added the column that should be next to it.  Also it is a width problem (When i inspect element, i see that keep_up is very long). However when i make it smaller, the show_thread does not want to come up

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123472/discussion-between-mehdi-dehghani-and-mitch).

Comment: Look at a responsive layout. Plenty of libraries out there that handles grids so you will not have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like #threadMenu is floated left, this pulls the element out of the flow of the document, so it will not effect the containing divs height!

You could use JS to get the #threadMenu height, then push the content down by this much, but thats not an ideal solution!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the following styles from #bottom

```
position: absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
```

Add a clearfix for #keep_up (see examples mentioned by Michael_B)

```
#keep_up:after {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  clear:both;
}
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/raghavtandon/d99g3ww0/4/)

Note: changed id="Middle" to id="middle" in your fiddle example

Comment: For me, this makes the footer go up, just like in the drawn example.

Comment: @Mitch Updated the answer - replaced with #keep_up. Also included jsfiddle example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the 'menu-items' on the image is the #thread_menu in the CSS. When you float something in the CSS, you're taking it out of the flow. Meaning they won't listen to what it's parents has to say.

What you can do is use display: flex; flex-direction: row; on the middle, force #thead_menu to use a base of 17% by using flex: 0 0 17%.

See https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ for detailed information on how to use flexbox